# Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: permissions, lamp

I have been using LAMP on my system for a while now, i decided to change ownership of the lampp dir from root to my account, now i'm getting this control user problem that never existed before. I have tried changing ownership back to root , but same problem ....

here the relevant config file section...and i've followed a bunch of the similar questions i found...none worked for me:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'daisy041093';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
*/

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit ../phpmyadmin/config-db.php**

Change the following lines as follows:

```
 $dbuser='pma';
 $dbpass='<your pma user's password>';
```

---

*From my more extensive post on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166687/how-do-i-enable-phpmyadmins-designer-view/39860070?noredirect=1#comment67008147_39860070).*

Note, on Debian this file is here: /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php